# call resources from a map - terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

any help with this please ?

I have one module to create multiple RGs and after i want to create in each RG a storage account.

```
---Modules
-----RG 
-------main.tf
-------variables.tf

---Infra
---resources.tf
---variables.tf
---terraform.tfvars
```

for the module RG  :

Here the main file  :

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  for_each    = var.resource_groups

    name      = each.key
    location  = each.value.location
    tags      = lookup(each.value,"tags",null) == null ? var.global_tags : merge(var.global_tags,each.value.tags)
}
```

Variables file

```
variable "resource_groups" {
  type        = map(any)
  description = "(Required) A list of Azure Resource Groups with locations and tags"
}
variable "global_tags" {
  type        = map(any)
  description = "(Optional) A map of tags to be applied globally on all Azure resources"
  default     = {}
}
```

When i create 03 RGs at the resources file :

```
module "resource-group-mult" {
  source    = "../modules/rg_multiple"
  resource_groups = var.resource_groups
  global_tags     = var.global_tags
}
```

and the variables file for the resource :

```
variable "resource_groups" {
 type        = map(any)
 description = "(Required) A list of Azure Resource Groups with locations and tags"
}
variable "global_tags" {
 type        = map(any)
 description = "(Optional) A map of tags to be applied globally on all Azure resource groups"
 default     = {}
}
```

and here the terraform tfvars file :

```
global_tags = {
  Provisioner  = "labo"
}
resource_groups = {
  Victrix01-rg = {
    location   = "canadacentral",
    tags       = {
      Owner      = "labo",
      Description = "labo"} }

  Victrix02-rg = {
    location   = "canadacentral",
    tags       = {
      Owner      = "labo",
      Description = "labo"} }
}
```

Now, if i want to create in each RG a storage account, how i can call it ?

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "storageaccountname"
  **resource_group_name      =  ?????** 
  location                 = "canadacentral"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "GRS"

  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You forgot to explain what's wrong with the current code and your current setup. Any errors?

Comment: When i create all RGs, how can i create the each storage acciunt in every RG ? How can i call all the RG ? I marked as ???? In the code

Answer (score 0):

I tested this deployment in my lab to create a storage account in each resource group.

I've added a variable for the Storage Account name to each of the Resource Group variables.

Because storage account names need to be unique, this name could also be a concatenated field with a [random calculated value](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/random/latest/docs/resources/string).

Here are my Terraform files:

**tfvars**:

```
global_tags = {
  Provisioner = "labo"
}

resource_groups = {
  Victrix01-rg = {
    storageAccountName = "staweuvictrix01"
    location           = "westeurope",
    tags = {
      Owner       = "labo",
      Description = "labo"
    }
  }

  Victrix02-rg = {
    storageAccountName = "staweuvictrix02"
    location           = "westeurope",
    tags = {
      Owner = "labo",
    Description = "labo" }
  }
}
```

**resources.tf**:

```
module "resource-group-mult" {
  source    = "../Modules/RG"
  resource_groups = var.resource_groups
  global_tags     = var.global_tags
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "examplestorage" {
  for_each                 = var.resource_groups
  name                     = each.value.storageAccountName
  resource_group_name      = each.key
  location                 = "westeurope"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you philip, i need your help ,we imagine that we will need the id instead of the name of each RG, how do I write it in code instead of each.key?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what the goal is. But if you want to use the name instead of the key, you should add the name to the tfvars 'resource_groups' map item.
If added, you can use the (example) statement: "each.value.resourceGroupName" for the Resource Group name.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, if i want to create in each RG a storage account, how i can call it ?

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "storageaccountname"
  **resource_group_name      =  ?????** 
  location                 = "canadacentral"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "GRS"

  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}
```

Replace with

```cs
data "azurerm_resource_group" "get" {
    for_each = var.resource_groups
    name = each.key
    location = each.value.location
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
    count = var.resource_groups
    resource_group_name = (data.azurerm_resource_group.get.*.name, count.index)
    location                 = "canadacentral"
    account_tier             = "Standard"
    account_replication_type = "GRS"
    tags = {
        environment = "staging"
      }
}
```